# Squeaking/ringing noise on Ford Mustang

Tags: noise, suspension

I have a Squeaking/ringing noise on Ford Mustang 1 year old with only 2000 miles. Ford investigating under warranty but havent found the problem despite a full inspection.
Its a brief loud noise from front passenger side that can be heard when going over bumps on that side,doesnt happen if going over bumps on driver side. There are no problems with driving the car, its just the noise.
I have also checked many things myself, theres no visible play in suspension components, and I cant find anything loose in the engine bay or under the front of the car on the engine and exhaust system, Ive recorded the sound with a mic attached to all main components and the noise is of similar volume all around the front passenger side of the car. One important point, is that when I drive trough a few inches of water on the passenger side, the noise stops for about the next 20 minutes of a journey. Can anyone suggest where the source of the noise might be? Here are links to sound recordings, one taken in the car and the other taken between outer wing (fender) on passenger side and engine bay:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AosOWHtE1HwDlhpdDrSgI_sKpUB5?e=grYFhq
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AosOWHtE1HwDlhlibzMWVIuJunug?e=M6jttL

Comment: This is impossible to answer without a sound sample.

Comment: This may be impossible to answer even with a sound sample... One noise we had to find turned out to be a loose bolt running up and down a channel and only found after removing seats and carpet then driving...

Comment: I had a car with a loud sound like a giant bass guitar string every time I hit a bump, turns out it was the hood prop vibrating after every bump. took many weeks by the dealer to find it and fix.

Comment: Ive added 2 sound recordings to the post.

Comment: My guess, the nut on the top of the passenger side front strut is 1/8th of a turn from fully tight.

Comment: One easy, safe test?  Engine off.  Hood open. Jack up each corner of the car one at a time.  Have someone sit inside the car, listen for the same squeak while you are doing that.